# Signature Mismatch

Tags: ocaml

The type of elements in semiring module is ElementS which is a Set of elements. When I define zero = ElementS.empty it says that there is type error as type element <> ElementS.t

I couldnt find any similar questions and havent been able to resolve this issue.

```
   (*semiring.ml*)
module type SEMIRING =
sig
    type elements
    type poly = elements polynomial
        type variable = int

    (** Constants **)
    val zero : elements (** Identity for + **)
.....
end
    module CountingSemiring : SEMIRING =
    struct

 module Ord : Carrier.Order =
 struct
      let vector_order= 2
 end

 module Z = Carrier.Make(Ord)

 module ElementS = Set.Make( 
   struct
     let compare = Pervasives.compare
     type t = Z
  end )

  type elements = ElementS 
  type varmap = elements IntMap.t
  type poly = elements polynomial

  let zero = ElementS.empty
end

(* carrier.ml *)
module Make (Ord:Order) =
struct
 let o = Ord.vector_order

 type t = Elementi.t array 

  let gen i = 
  if( i < o) then 
  let arr = Array.make o (Elementi.N 0) in
  Array.set arr i (Elementi.N 1)
  else 
   failwith "Out of bound generate"
....
end
```

> ```
> ERROR: Signature mismatch SEMIRING vs CountingSemiring
>        Values do not match:
>          val zero : ElementS.t
>        is not included in
>          val zero : elements
>  when they should be the same.
> ```

Comment: a set S and S.empty have different types. What is a way to get around this constraint in the present case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type elements = ElementS
```

this is probably a typo : you define elements to be a sum type with one constant constructor `ElementS`.

The compiler tells you that this type is incompatible with `ElementS.t`. So you should rather write:

```
type elements = ElementS.t
```